# Terminate Thread in Threadpool

Tags: java, threadpool

i've got an application with a possible number of threads. basicly the threads should work this:

- Main Thread
- CalculationThread
- CalculationThread
- CalculationThread

Adding / Executing those threads to a FixedThreadPool isn't the problem. The Thread itself calls a certain function in the Mainthread to submit the results. After this step, the thread should sleep until it will be called again for the next calucation.

The Mainthread holds a reference to a CalculationThread to submit updates to the thread and readd it to the pool to start the next calculation.

My Problem: How can I enforce a timeout for a certain thread? The enforcement of this timeout must also work, if a endless loop occurs

Answer (score 1):

You cannot enforce the timeout without cooperation from the thread, at least not in a sane way. You should code your calculation tasks so that they comply with the Java interruption mechanism. Basically, that means occasionally checking the `Thread.interrupted` return value and aborting on `true`.

The only other option is the ham-handed – and deprecated – `Thread.stop`, which can wreak general chaos, especially when done on a pool-managed thread.

Comment: The Problem is that the thread calls/wraps an external libary. So is there a method to throw the thread away with a minimal collateral damage?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't. This is a quite frequently asked question here, and I have never read any better suggestions.

Comment: Why not using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained)'s `ListenableFuture`s with a `FutureCallback` so you can do something if it works or it fails?

Comment: @mael OP is interested in neither success nor failure events.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik if i'll use Thread.stop the allocated system ressources will be wasted, because the jvm won't free it again.

Comment: Just have a look at any piece of your code and imagine the consequences of aborting it at an arbitrary point, like in the middle of a `try-finally`, or in the middle of a call to `HashMap.put`. That's the key difference between threads and full-blown processes: there is no isolation between threads.

Comment: You should not 'throw away' the thread (especially) while native code is running. - Can you implement the usual mechanisms for thread termination *around* the JNI calls?